# Is it possible to to define all my layout only with constraints?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to define the height of the constraintLayout1 30% of the available size. And the remaining for the constraintLayout2. But I want to define percentage not pixels.
The Button1 should be 50% with and the button2 the others 50%.
I want to define everything with constraints and not with fix values (as I am doing now `marginBottom="500dp`).
Is this possible to do in any way? I am using Android 3.6.2.

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#8BC34A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzZwz.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `layout_constraintVertical_weight` and `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.3">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#8BC34A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.7">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an easy way to do this is [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html)

You would basically say that you create a horizontal/vertical line at 0-100% of the width/height (in your case 30% or 50%) and then connect your buttons with that Guideline

Also it is bad practice to have multiple Constraintlayouts within eachother when not needed, you should only have one

Ask if you have any further questions

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.